# Arabic text shows strange characters Ø§Ù„ÙØ¨Ø§Ù‰ Ø§Ù†Ú¯Ù„ÙŠØ³Ù‰ ØŒ

Tags: unicode, arabic, farsi, charset

I have Arabic text (`.sql` pure text). When I view it in any document, it shows like this:

`Ø­Ø±Ù Ø§ÙˆÙ„ Ø§Ù„ÙØ¨Ø§Ù‰ Ø§Ù†Ú¯Ù„ÙŠØ³Ù‰ ØŒ Ø­Ø±Ù Ø§Ø¶Ø§ÙÙ‡ Ù…Ø«Ø¨Øª`

But when I use an HTML document with `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>`, it shows properly like this:

`حرف اول الفباى انگليسى ، حرف اضافه مثبت`

How can I convert it to readable text?

Comment: you need to tell the text editor to open it in the correct encoding

Comment: It's difficult to say if the .sql file is correct but viewed with the wrong encoding, or if the Arabic text has been incorrectly saved in the .sql file. First thing to try: use a text editor that lets you change the encoding, open the .sql file and change the encoding to UTF-8.

Comment: @phuclv I don't see the options. for example notepad++ does not have this option. can you suggest any software where I can do that?

Comment: @barnamah who said that? [Notepad++ has the option to select input encoding and also convert encoding](https://superuser.com/a/762475/241386)

Answer (score 4):

The Arabic text has been encoded to bytes using UTF-8.

You are explicitly telling the HTML document that the bytes are encoded in UTF-8, which is why any HTML viewer will be able to display the text correctly.

However, any other text viewer will not know the bytes are encoded in UTF-8, unless you put a UTF-8 BOM in front of the text, and the viewer supports BOMs.  Otherwise, as you are seeing, a text viewer may instead interpret the bytes in Latin-1 or similar encoding instead. So, you would have to manually tell the text viewer to interpret the bytes as UTF-8 instead. But how you actually do that depends on the particular text viewer you are using.  Not all viewers offer this option.

Comment: then how can I fix this current data so permanently I have correctly encoded data in the database?

Comment: @barnamah there is nothing to fix, because it is not really broken to begin with. The SQL file is simply encoded in UTF-8, so make sure the database engine you use to process that file supports UTF-8. Or, if you are storing UTF-8 bytes in the database, make sure the column has a UTF-8 charset/collation assigned to it, if the database supports that. Otherwise, just make sure any reader/writer of the column data uses UTF-8.

Comment: Once I opened the sql file in  Microsoft Edge which displayed it properly and then saved it with utf-8 and it helped. but now it does not work.